# Stalls on BlockingQueue

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

I am using large `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Its max capacity is approximately 150M. There is one producer and one consumer. 
When I measure the statistics of producer and consumer, I see some stalls.

For example, producer pushes elements to queue 1M/s and suddenly it decreases to 200K/s and then back to normal. 
The same is with consumer. When producer finishes, consumer works in normal rate, without stalls.

So is the reason about the `lock` over `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: that would be a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks for answer. Do you know what appropriate queue data structure should be used to avoid this? I don't need atomicity at all, only speed is what concerns me.